# Angular2: click listener with *ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a list of components and to attach a click event listener that registers the index of the component clicked.

I can achieve this by attaching the event listener at my leaf node, as it knows its index. But then I have to bubble the event up one more time than I might need to.  What I'd prefer to do is have the following at the parent of the leaves:

```
  template: `
    <trackpoint
        *ngFor='#tp of lapData; #i=index'
        [tp]='tp'
        [index]='i'
        [ngClass]="{selected:selectedTps[i]}"
        (click)='handleClick($event)'>
    </trackpoint>
  `,
```

and in my controller

```
handleClick(e:MouseEvent) {
   console.log(e);
   this.lapEventHandler.next({
   // I want to be able to access i from the template
  });
}
```

I've been examining the the MouseEvent object but although I can find the Trackpoint among the event parents, I cannot find the `index` property. Am I trying to do the impossible.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your code seems to add the event handler on each generated code but you explain that this is not what you actually want. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I started with the click handler in the `trackpoint` component, but I wanted to attach to trackpoint's parent - the code you see. Vlado provided a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
(click)='handleClick($event, i)
```

and

```
handleClick(e:MouseEvent, i: any)
```